# Multithreading: When would I use a Join?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I see online that it says I use `myThread.Join();` when I want to block my thread until another thread finishes. (One of the things I don't get about this is what if I have multiple threads).

But generally, I just don't get when I'd use `.Join()` or a condition that it's useful for. Can anyone please explain this to me like I'm a fourth grader? Very simple explanation to understand will get my answer vote.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Let's say you want to start some worker threads to perform some kind of calculation, and then do something afterwards with all the results.

```
List<Thread> workerThreads = new List<Thread>();
List<int> results = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => {
        Thread.Sleep(new Random().Next(1000, 5000));
        lock (results) {
            results.Add(new Random().Next(1, 10));
        }
    });
    workerThreads.Add(thread);
    thread.Start();
}

// Wait for all the threads to finish so that the results list is populated.
// If a thread is already finished when Join is called, Join will return immediately.
foreach (Thread thread in workerThreads) {
    thread.Join();
}

Debug.WriteLine("Sum of results: " + results.Sum());
```

---

Oh yeah, and don't use Random like that, I was just trying to write a minimal, easily understandable example.  It ends up not really being random if you create new Random instances too close in time, since the seed is based on the clock.

Comment: You need to add something like 'int value = i;' in the foor-loop before you're init a new Thread. Because 'i' can be increasing before a thread starts and the sum will be non-deterministic.

Answer (score 19):

In the following code snippet, the main thread calls [Join()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx) which causes it to wait for all spawned threads to finish:

```
static void Main()
{
    Thread regularThread = new Thread(ThreadMethod);
    regularThread.Start();

    Thread regularThread2 = new Thread(ThreadMethod2);
    regularThread2.Start();

    // Wait for spawned threads to end.
    regularThread.Join();
    Console.WriteLine("regularThread returned.");

    regularThread2.Join();
    Console.WriteLine("regularThread2 returned.");
}
```

Note that if you also spun up a thread from the thread pool (using QueueUserWorkItem for instance), Join would not wait for that background thread. You would need to implement some other mechanism such as using an AutoResetEvent.

For an excellent introduction to threading, I recommend reading Joe Albahari's free [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

Answer (score 12):

This is very simple program to demonstrate usage of Thread `Join`.Please follow my comments for better understanding.Write this program as it is.

```
    using System;
    using System.Threading;


    namespace ThreadSample
    {
        class Program
        {
            static Thread thread1, thread2;
            static int sum=0;
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                start();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            private static void Sample() { sum = sum + 1; }
            private static void Sample2() { sum = sum + 10; }

            private static void start() 
            {    
                thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Sample));
                thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Sample2));
                thread1.Start();
                thread2.Start();
             // thread1.Join(); 
             // thread2.Join();
                Console.WriteLine(sum);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
       }
}
```

1.First time run *as it is (with comments)* : **Then result will be 0(initial value) or 1(when thread 1 finished) or 10 (Or thread finished)**

2.Run with *removing comment `thread1.Join()`* : **Result should be always more than 1**.because `thread1.Join()` fired and thread 1 should be finished before get the sum.

3.Run with *removing all coments* :**Result should be always 11**

Comment: Might be some wording error for point 2.
Your thread1 and thread2 will only run 1 time, as no loops(for, while) was seen. So sum values would be either 0,1,10 or 11. "More than 1" in point 2 could be better refined to make better sense.

Comment: When executing 3 the result will not always be 11. It is still possible for both _thread1_ and _thread2_ to read the value of _sum_ as 0 and perform the addition before either perform assignment back to _sum_.

At the least, you must lock on an object around the calculation to ensure thread safety.
`private static object locker = new object();`

Then

`lock (locker)
{
  sum = sum + 1;
}`

Answer (score 11):

Join is used mainly when you need to wait that a thread (or a bunch of them) will terminate before proceding with your code.

For this reason is also particular useful when you need to collect result from a thread execution.

As per the Arafangion comment below, it's also important to join threads if you need to do some cleaning/housekeeping code after having created a thread.

Comment: Should mention that this can be important while cleaning up a process preparing for exit.

Answer (score 5):

Join will make sure that the treads above line is executed before executing lines below.

Answer (score 1):

Another example, when your worker thread let's say reads from an input stream while the read method can run forever and you want to somehow avoid this - by applying timeout using another watchdog thread:

```
// worker thread
var worker = new Thread(() => {
    Trace.WriteLine("Reading from stream");

    // here is the critical area of thread, where the real stuff happens
    // Sleep is just an example, simulating any real operation
    Thread.Sleep(10000);

    Trace.WriteLine("Reading finished");
}) { Name = "Worker" };
Trace.WriteLine("Starting worker thread...");
worker.Start();

// watchdog thread
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) => {
    var timeOut = 5000;
    if (!worker.Join(timeOut))
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Killing worker thread after " + timeOut + " milliseconds!");
        worker.Abort();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a delay of 300ms in method "Sample" and  a delay of 400ms in "Sample2" from devopsEMK's post would make it easier to understand.

By doing so you can observe that by removing the comment from "thread1.Join();"  line, the main thread waits for the "thread1" to complete and only after moves on.